# PHP придать правильный вид массиву

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой

У меня есть массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать ему вид [0] => string " "30", "13" "

Comment: Вы спрашиваете не то, что вам надо.

Comment: ``[0] => string " "30", "13" "`` - Что это за вид такой? И как предполагается представить весь массив в таком "правильном" виде?

Answer (score 1):

Если из строки с числами нужно получить массив с числами, смотрите в стороне `explode()`

upd

```
$array["labels"][0] = explode(", ", "30, 13")
```

Точнее не напишу, т.к. не достаточно входных данных)